# Grouping rows from an R dataframe together when randomly assigning to training/testing datasets

Tags: r, dataframe, random, training-data

I have a dataframe that consists of blocks of X rows, each corresponding to a single individual (where X can be different for each individual). I'd like to randomly distribute these individuals into train, test and validation samples but so far I haven't been able to get the syntax correct to ensure that each of a user's X rows are always collected into the same subsample.

For example, the data can be simplified to look like:

```
user    feature1     feature2
 1        "A"           "B"
 1        "L"           "L"
 1        "Q"           "B"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "P"           "E"
 2        "A"           "B"
 2        "R"           "P"
 2        "A"           "F"
 3        "X"           "U"
...       ...           ...
```

and then if I ended up randomly assigning the users to a train, test or validation set all of the rows for that user (the user number is unique) would be in the same set, and grouped together so that if user 1 was in the traininng set, for example, then the format would still be:

```
user    feature1     feature2
 1        "A"           "B"
 1        "L"           "L"
 1        "Q"           "B"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "P"           "E"
```

As a bonus I'd love to know if the solution to this could be extended to do k-folds cross validation, but so far I haven't even figured out this more simple first step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping rows from an R dataframe together when randomly assigning to training/testing datasets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857248/grouping-rows-from-an-r-dataframe-together-when-randomly-assigning-to-training-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sample():

```
# 60 % for training, 20% for testing & validation
indeces <- sample(1:nrow(df),nrow(df)*0.6)
df.train <- df[indeces,]
df <- df[-indeces,]

indeces <- sample(1:nrow(df),nrow(df)*0.5)
df.test <- df[indeces,]
df.validate <- df[-indeces,]
```

for k-fold cross validation :

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
fld <- createFolds(df$your_dependent_variable, k= 10,list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)
```

The above code splits the data into 10 folds. Run your model on each samples and validate them.

**Edited:**

```
user.df <- split( df , f = df$user )
```

this produces a separate data frame containing data for a particular user. use `user.df[[1]]` to access them individually.

Comment: This approach is (roughly) what I'd usually do, assuming I wanted the rows distributed independently of each other. In this case though, I want to make sure that all of the rows corresponding to a user fall into the same dataset.